# Copy, Transpose and delete Duplicate information VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to transpose data based on the cell information from another column.

I can fairly quickly with the macro below when I only have two data that are the same. My problem is when I hit more than one data that are the same.

For example:

```
Clients   What they want
    20    B
    20    C
    33    B
    33    C
    202   A
    202   B
    202   C
    55    A
    55    C
```

The macro I have is this

```
Sub TransposeDuplciateData()
    Sheets("Duplicate").Select
    While Range("A2") <> ""
        Range("B2").Select
        ActiveCell.Resize(2, 1).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Clients").Select
        Range("B1").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
        Sheets("Duplicate").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Wend
End Sub
```

The problem is when I hit client number 202, he wants three different things not only two.

I'm therefore looking for a macro that it would first recognize how many times the clients appear and from there copy the relevant information from column `B` and transpose it into my `Clients` sheet, then delete the entire rows from my `Duplicate` sheet (since I dealt with it) and move to the next clients information and do the same thing until there is no more clients information.

Here is the end results I would like it too look like

```
Clients Option 1    Option 2    Option 3    Option 4    
20      B            C              
33      B            C              
202     A            B            C         
55      B            C
```

Comment: I am not completely sure that I understand your requirement. Can you post a screenshot which shows how the output will look like for the data that you posted?

Comment: It doesn't seem to show it in a table but basically I have all my clents information on many rows. Column A is my clients number and columb B is what they want. I have in A1 20 and B1 is B then A2 is 20 again and B2 is C. Then when I hit clients number 202 his infomraiton in on three different row. Now what I want is to have in Sheet client column A with only one client number and all their options in the subsequent columns. So A2 would be 20 B2 would be B and C2 would be C. And when I hit client 202 it would be A4 is 202 B4 is A C4 is B and D4 is C. Hope this help clarify :-)

Comment: What you need is a Pivot like Axel mentioned below :)

Answer (score 0):

a possible way to achieve your desired outcome is to use a pivot table.
If you set Column A as Row, Column B as Column and values as count of Column B, you get the following output.

```
     A   B   C  
20       1   1 
33       1   1 
55   1       1
202  1   1   1
```

Would that help?

For a macro based solution, try the following code. It may need to be adapted to your exact need. Make also sure, column A is sorted in some kind of a way (this can also be done within the macro)

```
Sub remove_dub()

    With Sheets("Dublicate")
        Dim row_dubl As Integer
        Dim row_clie As Integer
        Dim col_clie As Integer

        row_dubl = 1
        row_clie = 1
        col_clie = 2

        While .Cells(row_dubl, "A") <> ""
            Sheets("Clients").Cells(row_clie, "A") = .Cells(row_dubl, "A")
            Sheets("Clients").Cells(row_clie, col_clie) = .Cells(row_dubl, "B")

            If .Cells(row_dubl, "A") = .Cells(row_dubl + 1, "A") Then
                row_clie = row_clie
                col_clie = col_clie + 1
            Else
                row_clie = row_clie + 1
                col_clie = 2
            End If

            row_dubl = row_dubl + 1
        Wend

    End With
End Sub
```

Best regards

Comment: I would rather have a macro than use pivot table simply because I don't want to have to update the pivot table all the time. I have a macro to update other pivote table in another worksheet but this one would start from scratch at every download, so one hit of a button would be easier :-)

Comment: I have added a macro, which should solve your issue. Make sure, column A is sorted

Comment: If necessary, you could delete the whole table in sheet `Dublicate` at the end of the macro

Comment: I'll try this one too to see which one is easier for me to manipulate if needs be. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Here is a macro which creates a user defined object as a class, which has the properties of Client and a dictionary of Opts (for Option).  You can easily add other properties, if you want to extend this.

**Set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime**

**EDIT:** Rename the class module `cClient`

### Class Module

```
Option Explicit
Private pClient As String
Private pOpt As String
Private pOpts As Dictionary

Public Property Get Client() As String
    Client = pClient
End Property
Public Property Let Client(Value As String)
    pClient = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Opt() As String
    Opt = pOpt
End Property
Public Property Let Opt(Value As String)
    pOpt = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Opts() As Dictionary
    Set Opts = pOpts
End Property
Public Function ADDOpt(Value As String)
    If Not pOpts.Exists(Value) Then
        pOpts.Add Key:=Value, Item:=Value
    End If
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pOpts = New Dictionary
    pOpts.CompareMode = TextCompare
End Sub
```

### Regular Module

```
Option Explicit
'Set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Sub OrganizeClientOptions()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim cC As cClient, dC As Dictionary
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim V As Variant, W As Variant

'Set worksheets
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet1")

On Error Resume Next
    Set wsRes = Worksheets("Results")
    If Err.Number = 9 Then
        Worksheets.Add.Name = "Results"
    End If
On Error GoTo 0
Set wsRes = Worksheets("Results")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1)

With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=2)
End With

'collect the data
Set dC = New Dictionary
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    Set cC = New cClient
    With cC
        .Client = vSrc(I, 1)
        .Opt = vSrc(I, 2)
        .ADDOpt .Opt
        If Not dC.Exists(.Client) Then
            dC.Add Key:=.Client, Item:=cC
        Else
            dC(.Client).ADDOpt .Opt
        End If
    End With
Next I

'Size vRes
J = 0
For Each V In dC.Keys
    I = dC(V).Opts.Count
    J = IIf(J > I, J, I)
Next V

ReDim vRes(0 To dC.Count + 1, 1 To J + 1)

'headers
vRes(0, 1) = "Client"
For J = 2 To UBound(vRes, 2)
    vRes(0, J) = "Option " & J - 1
Next J

'Data
I = 0
For Each V In dC.Keys
    I = I + 1
    vRes(I, 1) = V

    J = 1
    For Each W In dC(V).Opts
        J = J + 1
        vRes(I, J) = W
    Next W
Next V

'Write the results
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    With .Rows(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

### Results

[image]

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out :-)

Comment: @ValS Forgot to note that the Class module must be renamed `cClient`

Answer (score 0):

A bit "simplified" version:

```
Dim c As Range
Set c = [a2]
While c > ""
    While c = c(2)                          ' while c equals the cell below it
        c.End(xlToRight)(, 2) = c(2, 2)     ' get the second value below c
        c(2).Resize(, 2).Delete xlShiftUp   ' delete the 2 cells below c
    Wend
    Set c = c(2)
Wend
```